# GWT UI binder not seeing interface default methods

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I'm using `Dictionary` class to localize my application, since I want my texts to be files outside of the application, so I can change them without the need to compile the app again.

To be able to get the strings, I created class `StringIdentifiers`, that had all the methods like:

```
public String minute(){
   return getString("minute");
}
```

The method `getString()` basically just used a `Dictionary` to get the string from a JSON included into the page.

I then created subclass called Language, where I had some more logic (checking what language to use etc.). It all worked flawlessly, I used the `Language` subclass to access the Strings. Even in UIBinder.

Since there are more and more texts now, I decided to split these methods into separate classes. But since in Java I cannot do multiple inheritance, I decided to do it via interfaces. So instead of `StringIdentifiers` I created interfaces like: `LoginTexts`, `MenuTexts`, `EventLogTexts` etc. In these interfaces I specified `default` methods to get the appropriate strings. The `Language` class implements all the interfaces and also the `getString()` method.

Now it all works fine, I get instance of the Language class, I can use methods from the interfaces in the code, no errors.

BUT when it comes to UI binder, it doesn't show errors in editor, but at compilation it tells:

> [ERROR] Could not find no-arg method named minute in type
>   com.company.project.client.locale.Language

Does this mean, that UI binder is not able to see inherited default method from the interfaces? Really? I mean in the Java code, it is working normally.

Comment: It doesn't surprise me. I mean, Java 1.8 support in GWT (I mean FULL support) is somewhat of a new topic.
And considering the fact that GWT compiler works off of source code, I'm thinking it is not that surprising that default methods were ignored (even if it works in Java code)

Comment: Well since it works in Java code, I think there only is a problem with UIbinder, but yea, maybe I wanted too much. I guess I will have to find another way how to split the methods into separate files. Maybe make the interfaces class again, and keep them as attributes of the Language class.

Comment: What version of GWT SDK is used? There are some changes related to default methods in [Release Notes](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html)

Comment: Now I am using 2.8.1, I was using 2.8.0 before I think, but I do it with classes now. I think my idea was that I would only include _Language_ class anywhere and then had access to all the texts, even though they are in a different files/interfaces. Now I use classes that all inherit _getString()_ method from _Language_ class and if I want to use any text, I inject the correct text class (_MenuTexts_ for example).

Comment: "So I do not know if there is any progress with the default methods" ...

Comment: Just wanna add that even in GWT 2.8.2, uiBinder doesnt seem to be compatible with default methods

Answer (score 0):

Im experiencing the same issue, however, after searching I discovered this clever work-around written by Jos31fr: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9629

1. Define the interface assuming that GWT supports default methods.
2. In the class implementing the interface, redefine the default method as a call to the super-class.

```java
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;

    public class TestTextBox extends TextBox implements TestInterface {
        public void setFoo(String bar) {
            TestInterface.super.setFoo(bar);
        }
    }
```